# mpandroidchart annotation beside LimitLine?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart to create a line chart and I need to put two labels to indicate the Max and Min. Beside the LimitLine, is there another possible way to add a label to a specific position on the plot? Sometimes the LimitLine is overlapping with the lines in the plot. Is there a way to set the Min label under the line maybe? It seems the LimitLabelPosition only provide LEFT and RIGHT for now.

Thanks for mpandroidchart, this is a very great android charting library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question. (Apply to only MPAndroidChart-1.7.4)

In the LimitLine.java, I changed:

```
/** indicates the position of the LimitLine label */
private LimitLabelPosition mLabelPosition = LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP;

/** enum that indicates the position of the LimitLine label */
public enum LimitLabelPosition {
    LEFT_TOP, RIGHT_TOP, LEFT_BOTTOM, RIGHT_BOTTOM
}
```

And in the BarLineChartBase.java, I changed:

```
if (l.getLabelPosition() == LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP) {

   mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
   mDrawCanvas.drawText(label, getWidth() - mOffsetRight
   - xOffset,
   pos.y - yOffset, mValuePaint);

} else if (l.getLabelPosition() == LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_TOP) {

   mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
   mDrawCanvas.drawText(label, mOffsetLeft
   + xOffset,
   pos.y - yOffset, mValuePaint);

} else if (l.getLabelPosition() == LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM) {

   mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
   mDrawCanvas.drawText(label, getWidth() - mOffsetRight 
   - xOffset,
   pos.y + yOffset, mValuePaint);

} else if (l.getLabelPosition() == LimitLabelPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM) {

   mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
   mDrawCanvas.drawText(label, mOffsetLeft
   + xOffset,
   pos.y + yOffset, mValuePaint);

}
```

The codes above help me to put the label under the line.

Thank you Philipp Jahoda for providing this great android library again.